# Adjective to describe a significant natural disaster "which only occurs once every century/millennium"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that expresses the rarity in terms of scale or impact of an event (especially a natural disaster like a flood or an earthquake). Words like disastrous, catastrophic, and devastating all describe the severity of impact, but don't stress the chronological rarity. In Chinese, there is an expression 百年一遇 which literally means "seen only once every century". I'm wondering if there is an English word or expression for that.

Comment: The buzzword today is *a [**black swan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory#:~:text=The%20black%20swan%20theory%20or,with%20the%20benefit%20of%20hindsight.) event.*

Comment: *The 1996 flood was classified as one of Grand Forks' five worst; it was also [what is known as **a hundred-year flood**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+a+hundred+year+flood+such%22). Such phrases express the severity of a flood in terms of its probability, its statistical frequency.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various expressions like "50-year storm" or "100-year flood" that refer to events only expected every 50 or 100 years. [50 year storm](https://wavelengthmag.com/50-year-storms-lineup-knife-crime-point-break-fact-or-fiction/) is a surfing term popularised by the film Point Break. Wikipedia has an article on [100-year flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100-year_flood) which it defines as "a flood event that has a 1 in 100 chance (1% probability) of being equaled or exceeded in any given year". The NOAA even talks about a "[thousand-year storm](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/event-tracker/how-can-we-call-something-thousand-year-storm-if-we-don%E2%80%99t-have-thousand)". It seems that this is an expression that can be modified to your event or time period.

You can write "100-year flood" or "100 year flood" depending on your preference for hyphenation; the forms with a hyphen seem more common, but it's not a hard and fast rule.

Comment: The idiomatic expression is 'perfect storm'; [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/perfect-storm) includes the rarity factor (' an unusual combination of events or things that produce an unusually bad or powerful result') but the fixed expression (usually used metaphorically) doesn't spell this out. None of the 'storm' expressions works well for say a severe earthquake or volcanic eruption.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was actually trying to describe the volcanic eruption in Congo yesterday. I think "100-year" works well for a flood or storm, but not so well for an earthquake or volcanic eruption. But big thanks to everyone for different suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

**Watershed**

> an event or period that is important because it represents a big change in how people do or think about something:

**a watershed for sth/sb**

*The buyout was hailed on Wall Street as a watershed for private equity.*

**a watershed in sth/sb**

*The pay agreement was a watershed in the development of the company's labour relations system.*

*Last year witnessed a watershed change for American business.*

[Cambridge]